# Why this code is not generating any alert message

Tags: javascript, html

Here i have written some that is for validation on form in html and javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="registration">
<input style="font-size:16px;" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" onchange="checkName()" required />
</form>
<script>
function checkName()  
{   
    var uname=document.registration.Name.value;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
    if(uname.value.match(letters))  
    {   
                alert('fg');
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
        //uname.focus();  
    }  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please describe why it is not working?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? It looks like there's a stray `}` after the function.

Comment: I have made few changes kindly recheck it

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Does *anything* happen? Are there errors?

Comment: it is not displaying any alert boxes

Comment: Right. Have you checked for errors in the developer console?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to get the value property TWICE. Like such:

```
var uname=document.registration.Name.value;

if(uname.value.match(letters))
```

Your uname variable already contains the value, so you don't need to get it again. Change your if statement to this...

```
if (uname.match(letters))
```

And it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `onchange` with `input type = "text"` is quite uncommon
`onchange` event usually occurs only after you leave (`blur`) the control.
`onchange` is mainly associated with change of `select` element.
For your case it is better to use  `keydown, keyup` and `keypress` events as well.

**HTML**

```
<input style="font-size:16px;" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" onkeyup="checkName()" required />
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2h6vdjz/2/)

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. And it doesn't work.

Comment: @ManoDestra his question was not generating alert message this question was answered before he edited and removed the alert outside if block. I guess you missed that part & onchange is not right event handler for text which I mentioned in the answer . Thank you

Comment: But it doesn't work though. The problem is that he's trying to get the value property after he's already got the value property. And your fiddle above makes the same error. You may wish to revise your answer given that. Not trying to be rude. Just trying to help :)